# Disabling dm-verity using 9008(edl) mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot, system, images

My device blocks fastboot flash command, so I can only flash images using QFIL under 9008(edl) mode. By enabling `OEM Unlock` in dev settings, Magisk-patched boot image works well.

However, when I flash a self-builded OrangeFox recovery, device refuses to boot into recovery  (system rom is working) and shows the red `g.co/ABH` message:

```
<!>
Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and will not boot.
...
```

Since I have access to 9008/edl mode, can I disable dm-verity by modifying system with QFIL or something?

Comment: magisk does re-sign boot.img with it's in original AVBv1 signature, that's why it booted on locked bootloader. if you want disable AVB unlock bootloader first

Comment: @alecxs I do enabled "OEM unlock bootloader" in android developer settings, but boot splash screen still shows "device state - locked".

Comment: Can I sign the recovery image as well or ask Magisk to sign it?

Comment: *OEM Unlock* only sets `get_unlock_ability` please inform yourself how to unlock bootloader (and risks). No you can't sign recovery.img because verification is secured different (you *can* actually sign it with osm0sis AIK but it's pointless). If your goal is to recover data off device your only chance is adb enabled in boot.img

Comment: https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/avb

Comment: I still can't unlock bl even if OEM unlock enabled:...
FAILED (remote: Unlock is not allowed!)
finished. total time: 0.001s I'm giving up....

Comment: unlocking is manufacturer specific, some require mi account and own unlock tool, some require unlock apk, some unlock code for fastboot. some don't allow unlocking at all where special hack is required. you haven't mentioned device model that's why you should inform yourself